# Vyatta Firewall structure and Interface Direction

Tags: router, firewall

I've just purchased a [Ubiquity EdgeRouter ER-8](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter/), and I'm working on configuring the firewall. In particular I'm confused about the direction "Local" for the interface I've defined as the WAN, and how I can use it to prevent exposing the router management protocols (ssh/https) to the outside world.

[Per the manual](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configuring-interface-based-firewall-on-the-vyatta-network-appliance) Rulesets can be applied on any interface, in one of three directions:

- In:  Traffic arriving on a port
- Out: Traffic exiting a port
- **Local: Traffic destined for the router itself**

My questions are:

1. Would there be any "local" direction traffic other than to the management web/ssh interfaces? Would response traffic like NTP, RIP, DNS masq, etc, originating from the router itself come in via the "local" direction?
2. If I apply a rule to drop all packets to WAN_LOCAL will that block requests to the management interfaces from the WAN, but allow requests from the LAN (since there is no LAN_LOCAL ruleset)?
3. Does traffic arriving at WAN_LOCAL get filtered by WAN_IN first? if I have a standard Stateful Filter on WAN_IN (eg accept NAT'ed responses, drop everything else) prevent the need for a ruleset on WAN_LOCAL at all?

Comment: Why can't you simply change the password on the admin account (ubnt) ?

Comment: Thats the first thing I did, but with bruteforce attacks, etc, I'd much rather explicitly block access to the management webapp entirely from the WAN. this is a home networking scenario, even if the router is more than your standard SOHO type device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice looking router.

Q1 Answer: No. The only traffic considered local would be, as you mentioned, ssh and webui traffic, as well as DHCP server traffic if you're utilizing the DHCP server feature of the router.

Q2 Answer: Yes. That would drop all traffic destined for the router from the WAN. I suggest creating a rule named MgmtAccess (order it above the drop rule) that permits tcp traffic from an outside source in case you need to remote manage it from another location. A datacenter for example, or your home.

Q3 Answer: No. Rulesets handle their rules separately from one another.

I like to approach firewalls with paranoia. I'd start by creating three rulesets for each interface (in, out, local), with the default action of in and local being 'drop'. Out can be accept. I'd then add rules (observe order), to permit traffic as I go from there. Give them good names. If eth0 goes to the WAN, call those rulesets WAN_IN, WAN_LOCAL, WAN_OUT. If eth7 goes to the storage network, call it STORAGE_IN... You get it. Give the rules descriptive names as well to make management easier down the line.

Default Account Destruction: Create a new user and delete the original. This will prevent brute force attacks against the default account. Treat your user names like passwords. Keep them secret. Keep them safe.

Comment: Thanks! That clarfifies things nicely. On the topic of DNS, do you still find we need to create UDP allow rules for DNS responses? It looks like NAT has improved a good bit in terms of UDP (or that DNS is tending to TCP nowadays) but I'm not having the problems I've traditionally had, even without a UDP/53 allow rule from the known servers I use.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you implement a network level firewall at the server, like iptables, you have to explicitly permit each type of traffic if you don't permit all. That'll never change.

Answer (score 2):

1. Potentially. For example, if you use the router on a small network to cache DNS requests, then the DNS traffic will hit the LOCAL interface. Same thing if you use it for DHCP and any other network service.
2. See above. If you want use the router to cache DNS requests, then you will have to permit its LOCAL to talk to WAN, just like LAN does.
3. Rulesets are independent, and it may be useful for clarity of configuration to be explicit with what is blocked. So I would prefer to have all the rules stating the intent. With that in mind I would have WAN_LOCAL.

Some time ago I have visualised the thinking process for the case where there is no services inside router which need WAN access for ER POE8.

[It is still on the GitHub, you can see if it helps you.](https://github.com/didenko/er_poe_fw/tree/5c0290823dbba0f3dae214d3e9883962b5ef9e50)

Comment: I generally implement a Spoof Killing rule on my WAN, to kill traffic that appears to be coming from my internal subnet, but on the WAN interface. Do I need a simmilar protection on my WAN_LOCAL ruleset? Thats a great link by the way. I wonder how I missed it when researching this issue.

Comment: @FrankThomas, Glad you find it useful. Purpose of the visuals was to help me to reason about the configuration - only in terms of interfaces and traffic flows. I am not a security engineer, so it would be irresponsible to post a configuration which may be perceived as complete.

The one posted is a skeleton - DDOS and Spoof protections, DMZ access and other features should be added based on use cases specific to the network. I am totally with you that those generally make a lot of sense to add.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent unauthorized access to router services from the WAN interface, just change the default password on the admin account (ubnt).

See the article [Password Recovery Speeds](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi).
It describes maximal crack time for a random password, by password length
and the characters used.

For example, the time needed to crack `B33r&Mug` by a distributed network of super-computers (NSA) is estimated as 83 days, while a high-end workstation will need more than 2 Years. This is because that password uses upper- and lower-case,
as well as numerics and special characters, while still being rather short
(8 characters).